# Why are some files not recognized by .gitgnore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have taken over a Vue/Gridsome project. The project can be started via the
docker-compose.yml file. After booting the node container, all files in the .docker folder (~4000 files) were prepared for the GIT commit.

I then added the .docker folder in the `.gitignore`. Instead of ~4000 Files
there are now only 6 files from the .docker folder. And I wonder why it
doesn´t ignore these files although I put the whole folder `.docker` into the
`.gitignore` folder.

#### Question: Why are these files not ignored?

**My .gitignore**

```sh
.bash_history (.docker/data/node)
update-notifier-npm.json (.docker/data/node/.config/configstore)
cli.json (.docker/data/node/.config/configstore/update-notifier-@gridsome)
anonymous-cli-metrics.json (.docker/data/node/.npm)
565911....de (.docker/data/.npm/index-v5/2b/b7)
30c54c....OO (.docker/data/.npm/index-v5/2b/b7)
```

**.gitignore when i was clone the project**

```
*.log
.cache
.DS_Store
src/.temp
node_modules
dist
.env
.env.*
```

**then i add .docker folder to .gitgnore**

```
.docker
```

Comment: Please share the `.gitignore` file? Have the files been tracked already?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added the .gitignore to my question.

Comment: You seem to have added `docker` not `.docker` to the gitignore file? Please also confirm whether you're already tracking these files.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Im sorry for typo. I have corrected it in my question.

Comment: No need to apologise. Typos are critical in the gitignore. It's the difference between it working and not.

Comment: @evolutionxbox You are right. But i wrote it correctly in the .gitgnore file and cant understand why im not able to ignore this six files above.

Comment: If you have added these files before you added the `.gitignore` entry, you must delete the files again from your git repo. See [git rm](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-rm)

Comment: @PeterKrebs I think that is the solution. I will try and give feedback. Thank you Peter!

Comment: @KrassVerpeilt I made it an answer and linked to the documentation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Remove files from the Git repository

Adding a file or directory in `.gitignore` does not remove them from the repository for you, because that might be a costly operation to do.

Files you have already added in the past must be removed again. This way you could set up some output directory with default files, but no additional files are added when the building process is complete.

Consider using `git rm`:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-rm

---

A file added to the repository is considered *tracked*. All changes are keeping *tracked of*.

When people where asking "Please also confirm whether you're already tracking these files." or "Have the files been tracked already?" (@evolutionxbox) they were hinting at exactly that.