# Make Git hide a folder when checking out a different branch

Tags: git, github-pages, git-branch, gitignore

I am creating a tutorial for a group of students learning React.

I want to create a separate branch for each step. Each branch will contain a solution to the previous step and instructions on how to complete the next step.

I also want to use GitHub Pages to demonstrate the outcome of each step. In order to do this, my gh-pages branch needs to have access to all the intermediate steps. I'll explain more about this below.

My plan is to create a directory for each step: Step_01/, Step_02/ and so on. I imagined that I could use `.gitignore` to hide the directories that are not relevant to the current step, and to how only the directory for the current step:

```
Step_*
!Step_XX
```

(where XX is the number of the current step).

This means that I can simply alter the following files in each branch:

> index.js (to point render `Step_XX/App`)
> README.md (to provide instructions for the current step)
> .gitignore (to hide the directories for other steps

However, when I alter .gitignore to ignore `Step_01/`, this directory still remains visible, although changes to it are no longer tracked. I would like Git to hide it for me.

If I can get this to work, then, for my gh-pages branch, I can create an `index.js` file that uses `react-router-dom` to show a different page for each step. In the gh-pages branch, .gitignore will not ignore any of the `Step_XX` directories.

---

My specific question is: how can I get Git to hide a previously visible directory when the currently checked out branch contains an instruction in .gitignore not to track that directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are some files not recognized by .gitgnore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127452/why-are-some-files-not-recognized-by-gitgnore)

Comment: You can't. You have the wrong impression of how Git works in the first place: every commit stores *every file* and *no directories*. As you switch from one commit to another, Git removes the files that came out of that one commit (removing any directories that become empty in the process) and then creates the files from the other commits (creating any directories needed in the process).

Comment: Once a file is committed, it is *not ignored even if listed in `.gitignore`*. You must *remove* the file (which does not affect its presence in other commits) and commit the result, making a new commit in which the file *does not exist* and now when checking out *that* commit, the file is removed if it was there because of some other commit.