# Ignore everything but specific filetype

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm setting up a git repository, But I only want specific types to be added to git.
For example I'll have the following files:

```
/door/index.md
/door/photo.png
/door/video.mp4
```

Via `.gitignore`, I only want the `index.md` and `photo.png` files to be synced, Anything else needs to be ignored.
I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
/*
/*/
!.gitignore
!/**/*.md
!**/*.md
!*.md
```

Comment: You could always ignore _everything_ and then ‘forcefully’ add what you want: `git add -f door/index.md door/photo.png`

Comment: Did you know: gitignore does not ignore files that have already been added to the index. You cannot add and commit everything first and magically ignore those files later.

Comment: FYI: Removing files from git that were added before you created a gitignore rule can be done with `git rm`. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71128947/10441671)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? This might as well be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Using a VCS to not-version files just feels wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [git help ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) (emphasis mine):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. *It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.*

So that's what happens, everything is ignored per `*` and later `!`s have no effect.

Having said that, you can easily debug your `.gitignore` using [`git check-ignore -v path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore)